# Gradle Errors on starting first Android Studio Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-resources, android-developer-api

I've merely just opened the Android Development Studio, following the tutorial on the main site, and am having the following "Gradle Build" errors preventing me from building my app:

[image: Gradle Error]

Is anyone familiar with what causes this error? Looks like some kind of app compatibility issue, but the source code being pointed to is auto-generated by the IDE.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of SDK have you installed ?

Comment: Solved this. Found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32084654/1751090). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the Android SDK manager from Android Studio.  Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> Launch Standalon SDK Manager (for me at least).  Then look at Android 6.0 (API 23) node in the tree. Install everything that's there.  This sounds like you haven't run the Android SDK Manager to get your initial packages in.

Healy in Tampa

[image: launch android sdk manager]

[image: install package 23]

Comment: I haven't tested this because I got mine working from the gradle.build file, but this looks like the good conceptual explanation for my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Keep posting this if it doesn't work out.  I've been blogging my adventures with Android + Windows-10 at http://www.devfish.net/?tag=/Android .  Working and fun, but challenging to get it going at first.